# Sequencer API: How do I listen to NOTE_ON events?

Tags: java, midi

How do I properly listen to `NOTE_ON` events when using the Sequencer API? Considering you can't directly listen to `NOTE_ON` events, they recommended [this approach](https://archive.org/details/head-first-java-2nd-edition/page/390/mode/1up?view=theater) in the Head First Java book: you register a `ControllerEventListener` that listens to a dummy event (they used 127 as the event number) which occurs at the same time as the event you want to listen to. It kind of works but here's the problem: my sounds now lack the smooth transitions between them. Somehow, adding the listener affected the output. You may hear for yourself by running the code below as is and then running it after uncommenting the blocks that are commented out

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MidiPlayer player = new MidiPlayer();
        player.playRegularPiano();
    }
}
```

```java
import static javax.sound.midi.ShortMessage.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MidiPlayer {
    private static final int KEYBOARD_CHANNEL = 1;
    private static final int PERCUSSION_CHANNEL = 9;
    private static final int MAGIC_NUMBER_THAT_MEANS_SEQUENCE_IS_FINISHED = 47;
    private static final int HOOK_EVENT_NUM = 127; // as I understand, it's arbitrary number: any non-reserved int would do

    public void playRegularPiano() {
        playInstrument(KEYBOARD_CHANNEL, Keyboards.REGULAR_PIANO);
    }
    
    // more playX() methods

    @SneakyThrows
    private void playInstrument(int channel, int instrument) {
        Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        sequencer.open();
//
//        sequencer.addControllerEventListener(event ->
//                System.out.println("la-la"), new int[]{HOOK_EVENT_NUM});

        Sequence sequence = getSequence(channel, instrument);
        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);

        MetaEventListener listener = getClosingListener(sequencer);
        sequencer.addMetaEventListener(listener);

        sequencer.start();

    }

    private Sequence getSequence(int channel, int instrument) throws InvalidMidiDataException {
        Sequence sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
        MidiEventBuilder builder = new MidiEventBuilder();
        Track track = sequence.createTrack();
        ShortMessage firstMessage, secondMessage;
        MidiEvent instrumentPick, noteOn, noteOff, hookEvent;

        instrumentPick = builder.withCommand(PROGRAM_CHANGE)
                .withChannel(channel)
                .withFirstByte(instrument)
                .withSecondByte(80)
                .withTick(0)
                .build();
        track.add(instrumentPick);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            noteOn = builder.withCommand(NOTE_ON)
                    .withChannel(channel)
                    .withFirstByte(54 - i)
                    .withSecondByte(80)
                    .withTick(i + 1)
                    .build();
            track.add(noteOn);
//
//            hookEvent = builder.withCommand(CONTROL_CHANGE)
//                    .withChannel(channel)
//                    .withFirstByte(HOOK_EVENT_NUM)
//                    .withSecondByte(0)
//                    .withTick(i + 1)
//                    .build();
//            track.add(hookEvent);

            noteOff = builder.withCommand(NOTE_OFF)
                    .withChannel(channel)
                    .withFirstByte(54 - i)
                    .withSecondByte(80)
                    .withTick(i + 1 + 20)
                    .build();
            track.add(noteOff);
        }

        for (int i = 8; i < 25; i++) {
            noteOn = builder.withCommand(NOTE_ON)
                    .withChannel(channel)
                    .withFirstByte(54 - (7 - (i - 7)))
                    .withSecondByte(100)
                    .withTick(i + 1)
                    .build();
            track.add(noteOn);
//
//            hookEvent = builder.withCommand(CONTROL_CHANGE)
//                    .withChannel(channel)
//                    .withFirstByte(HOOK_EVENT_NUM)
//                    .withSecondByte(0)
//                    .withTick(i + 1)
//                    .build();
//            track.add(hookEvent);

            noteOff = builder.withCommand(NOTE_OFF)
                    .withChannel(channel)
                    .withFirstByte(54 - (7 - (i - 7)))
                    .withSecondByte(100)
                    .withTick(i + 1 + 20)
                    .build();
            track.add(noteOff);
        }
        return sequence;
    }

    private MetaEventListener getClosingListener(Sequencer sequencer) {
        return (metaMessage) -> {
            if (metaMessage.getType() == MAGIC_NUMBER_THAT_MEANS_SEQUENCE_IS_FINISHED) {
                sequencer.close();
            }
        };
    }

    private static class Keyboards {
        private static final int REGULAR_PIANO = 1;

        // more constants
    }

    private static class MidiEventBuilder {
        private int command;
        private int channel;
        private int firstByte;
        private int secondByte;
        private int tick;

        private MidiEventBuilder withCommand(int command) {
            this.command = command;
            return this;
        }

        private MidiEventBuilder withChannel(int channel) {
            this.channel = channel;
            return this;
        }

        private MidiEventBuilder withFirstByte(int firstByte) {
            this.firstByte = firstByte;
            return this;
        }

        private MidiEventBuilder withSecondByte(int secondByte) {
            this.secondByte = secondByte;
            return this;
        }

        private MidiEventBuilder withTick(int tick) {
            this.tick = tick;
            return this;
        }

        private MidiEvent build() throws InvalidMidiDataException {
            ShortMessage message = new ShortMessage(command, channel, firstByte, secondByte);
            return new MidiEvent(message, tick);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I listen to `NOTE_ON` events in a way that doesn't compromise the sound?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to have Note-ONs without the corresponding Note-OFFs: on many synths it will use up all the polyphony.

If note sound is "cut", it means that the Note-OFF happened "too soon" (change the tick position of the Note-OFF). Of course it depends on the sound nature (a piano note will ring much longer than a drums kick) and on the tempo.

Also, if you want to listen to **all** Note-ON events of a track, just use a MidiReceiver connected to the Sequencer, it will avoid to add dummy events. The book "trick" with the custom Contrller event is OK when you want for example to be notified on every beat.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I used the same channel as my `NOTE_ON` message. If I change it to a different one, the problem disappears

```java
            hookEvent = builder.withCommand(CONTROL_CHANGE)
                    .withChannel(Math.max(1, (channel + 1) % 16)) // note this change
                    .withFirstByte(HOOK_EVENT_NUM)
                    .withSecondByte(0)
                    .withTick(i + 1)
                    .build();
            track.add(hookEvent);
```

Notice I used `Math.max(1, (channel + 1) % 16)` instead of simply `channel + 1`. If `channel` equals 16 (and there are only 16 of them), `16 + 1` causes a runtime exception. `(channel + 1) % 16` is problematic too since if `channel` is 16, the expression produces 0 which is an illegal `channel` value (MIDI channels are one-based)

It's probably not the most elegant solution, but I hope you get the idea